# Get div tag scroll position using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

How do I get the amount of scroll in a div tag using JavaScript? Please provide me with an example.

I don't want to use jQuery, only JavaScript.

Comment: @Alex: `ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side.` Seriously though, it's not accurate to say that - jQuery is a JavaScript library; the two are thus quite different.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this code snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function scrollPos() {
            var div = document.getElementById("myDiv").scrollTop;
            document.getElementById("pos").innerHTML = div;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
    <div id="pos">
    </div>
    <div id="myDiv" style="overflow: auto; height: 200px; width: 200px;" onscroll="scrollPos();">
        Place some large content here
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: var div = document.getElementById("myDiv").scrollTop; this will not work in firefox

Answer (score 37):

you use the scrollTop attribute

```
var position = document.getElementById('id').scrollTop;
```

Comment: If you are navigating in a horizontal scroll bar scrollLeft might be the property you need.