# How to know what part of HTML is the user on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I want to know how I can get what section or part of my html I’m currently on. An example 
So how do I know if a user has already scrolled down over part 2 using JavaScript 
Or if they’re currently at part 1

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<section class=“part 1”>
</section>
<section class= “part2>
</section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get div tag scroll position using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373667/get-div-tag-scroll-position-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The following codes will give you a little idea about how to handle this situation. Essentially you are going to want to get the scrollbar position which you can do using:

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop
```

You also want to get a range where the element you are looking for resides, in our case, it is `.part1` and `.part2`. We can get that range by using `offsetTop` as the beginning of the limit and `offsetTop + clientHeight` to determine the end.

You are going to have to keep track of the window scroll event.

The following example is generic:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0 
        && document.documentElement.scrollTop < $('.part2').offset().top ) {
        $('div').html("At part1")
    } else {
         $('div').html("At part2")
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ctt8ua8/1)

Likewise, if you want a little bit of modularity:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    let watchList = ['part1', 'part2', 'part3'];

    let scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    for (var classname of watchList) {
        let el = document.getElementsByClassName(classname)[0];
        if (scrollTop > el.offsetTop &&
            scrollTop < el.offsetTop + el.clientHeight) {
            $('div').html("At <strong>"+classname+"</strong>");
        }
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ctt8ua8/3/)

The possibilities are limitless to continue and make this more useful, but I'll leave that up to you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use is[":focus"] function to find which div has focus currently.

```
if($(".part1").is(":focus"))
{
//you code
}
else if($(".part2").is(":focus"))
{
//you code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mouseenter function it fires when the mouse goes into that div for the first time.

```
$(".part1").on('mouseenter', function(){
  //your command
});
```

you can use mouseover function to find where is mouse right now. it fires when mouse moves inside that div.

```
$(".part1").on('mouseover', function(){
  //your command
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascripts offsetTop functionality. This is a parameter that returns how far down from the top a div is in the number of pixels.

It can also return how far down the user has scrolled when called on the window object itself. Then it's just a matter of math. See if the user has scolled down far enough to be past the div in reference.

For example:

```
var part1DivOffset = document.getElementsByClassName("part 1")[0].offsetTop;
var part2DivOffset = document.getElementsByClassName("part2")[0].offsetTop;
var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
```

This code will get you 3 variables. The first 2 lines save the offsetTop of the div's. While the third line detects how far down the user has scrolled. Then you can do math with the variables:

```
if(scrollTop >= part1DivOffset){
  //we are past part1
}
if(scrollTop >= part2DivOffset){
  //We are past part 2
}
if(scrollTop >= part1DivOffset && scrollTop < part2DivOffset){
  //We are past part 1 but not past part 2
}
```