# Add class when scroll down in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am making mobile web using React.js.

How to toggle class to div when scroll down/up only in specific div ?

This is I tried so far.
My code problem is that it toggle class only when reach to top.

```
const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
   window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
     setScroll(window.scrollY > 50);
   });
 }, []); 

<div class="area">This area can Scroll</div>
<div className={scroll ? "hide" : "show"}>toggle class here</div>
```

Comment: `window.scrollY` will give you the scroll value of the browser window, not the specific div. Use a reference to the element and `scrollTop`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373667/get-div-tag-scroll-position-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `onScroll` event to your `div` that you want to make scrollable and attach a reference to it using `useRef` hook. Everytime your div scrolls, fire a function `handleScroll` and set your scroll state accordingly. You will need to set some height and give `overflow-y:scroll` to your scrollable div to actually see it. This should help you out.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(false);
  const divRef = React.useRef();

  const handleScroll = (e) => {
    const scrolledFromTop = divRef.current.scrollTop;
    console.log(scrolledFromTop);
    setScroll(scrolledFromTop > 50);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className={scroll ? "hide" : "show"}>toggle class here</div>
      <div className="area" onScroll={handleScroll} ref={divRef}>
       
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can run the codesandbox here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-sanderson-3otq4?file=/src/App.js:0-761

Answer (score 0):

Function handleScroll got included prop 'target' so useRef is not necessary.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [scrolled, setScrolled] = useState(false);

  const handleScroll = (event) => {
    const scrolledFromTop = event.target.scrollTop;
    setScroll(scrolledFromTop > 50);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className={scrolled ? "hide" : "show"}>
        toggle class here
      </div>
      <div className="area" onScroll={handleScroll}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```